# Setting a PHP Class Private value to a variable

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I am trying to edit a PHP class for paginating the query results. The number of records returned each page is set using this code

```
private $_limit_per_page = 20;
```

As can be seen this is set to 20, but I want to set this on each page where the code is used using the variable $paginate.

```
$paginate = 20;
```

Then in the Paginator class

```
private $_limit_per_page = $paginate;
```

I have tried to put the code in another class, but as I am not very conversant with the coding requirements, I am struggling a little bit, so any help would be much appreciated.

Phil

Comment: Do you have access to the class that uses the private property

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly,Yes I have access to the files

Comment: THen change property to public or cretae a getter method

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
class Pag { //create pagination class
  private $_limit_per_page;  //set private variable

  function __construct($limit = 20){  //set contructor to populate the limit to 20 by default, but override if something is passed
    $this->_limit_per_page = $limit;  //set the value to whatever was passed
  }
  function showMe() { //create a function that can output the variable, so you can see if it worked
    echo $this->_limit_per_page;  //output the variable
  }
}
$paginate = new Pag(35);  //instantiate the class, but override the limit to 35

echo $paginate->showMe(); //run it
```

Comment: pendo, thanks for this. It is not quite what I need but your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a public setter method in your class with the private var.
This could look like

```
public function SetPageLimit($page_amount){
  $_limit_per_page = $page_amount
}
```

You can call this one where you need it with

```
$something = new YourClassWherePrivateIs();
$something->SetPageLimit($paginate);
```

or if you make the function above static with

```
  YourClassWherePrivateIs::SetPageLimit($paginate);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mayrhofer, many thanks for this, your response has prompted me to look into this method and I think that I should be able to make this work :) Much Appreciated

Comment: You're Welcome. You should mark your question as answered if this solved it for you.